# Hierarchical gallery

Tags: gallery, hierarchical

I want several galleries, every gallery containing several images.

What is the proper way to do this two-level structure?

I'd make every element of each gallery a post.

Comment: i'm having trouble understanding your last sentence. each sub-gallery has several images that are posts?

Comment: @peteroak: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

### Wordpress Posts *(First level)*

> Yes, the posts feature can be used as a gallery. WordPress provides nice [`short code`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) to show all the attached images in post. While adding galleries make sure they point to attachment page not to the real file.
>
> When user clicks on any of image from the gallery they'll get to the attachment page.

### Attachment template *(Second level)* - [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Attachment)

> *An "**attachment**" is a special post that holds information about files uploaded through the Media upload system.*
>
> You can use attachment template to show image as post and I guess, by little configuration you can enable comments for attachment posts too.